# Python video decoding _without_ open-cv

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, dependency-management, video-codecs

I'm creating a lightweight application that should act as a shallow user interface to configure a camera and preview its video stream.

The stream comes YUV- or Motion-JPEG encoded (and maybe some others), and I would want to display it into a PySide6 'Image' item.

Being a dependency freak, and a spoiled one (C++ background), I don't want users to pay for what they don't use.  So I want to avoid the client having to install anything that has not to do with this app: no image recognition, no web scraping, not even a random xkcd retriever or differential equation solver.  Yes, some qt libraries.

Now when [searching](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=python%20video%20codecs) around, I find *lots* of ways to decode images with OpenCV.

This application is to do any linear algebra, nor computer vision.  Is there a mature python library that is dedicated to video decoding?  Or am I looking for the wrong thing?  Should I turn to the operating system to look for decoders?  Is this an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: *"not even a random xkcd retriever"* :D Python has one already built-in ... and anti-gravity.

Comment: @KlausD. you mean `matplotlib.pyplot.xkcd`?